# Why get_class_average(class_list) does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why get_class_average(class_list) returns "string indices must be integers", all previous functions seem to work correctly? It should count the average for the whole class, using previous functions reused.

```
lloyd = {
   "name": "Lloyd",
   "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
   "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
   "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
   "name": "Alice",
   "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
   "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
   "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
   "name": "Tyler",
   "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
   "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
   "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

def average(lst):
   average = float(sum(lst)) / len(lst)
   return average

def get_average(student):
   score = average(student['homework']) * 0.1 + average(student['quizzes']) * 0.3 + average(student['tests']) * 0.6
   return score


def get_letter_grade(score):
   if score >= 90:
       return "A"
   elif 80 <= score < 90:
       return "B"
   elif 70 <= score < 80:
       return "C"
   elif 60 <= score < 70:
       return "D"
   elif score < 60:
       return "F"

def get_class_average(class_list):
   '''
   get_class_average(['lloyd', 'alice', 'tyler'])
   '''
   total_class = 0
   for student in class_list:
       get_average(student)
       total_class = total_class + get_average(student)

   average_class = total_class / len(class_list)
   return average_class
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call it this way:

```
get_class_average([lloyd, alice, tyler])
```

The way you actually called it, `get_class_average(['lloyd', 'alice', 'tyler'])`, it tries to access `'lloyd'['homework']`, which doesn't make sense; `'lloyd'` is a string, not a `dict`.

---

If you want to be able to pass the names, you'll have to use yet another dictionary:

```
students = {'lloyd': lloyd, 'alice' : alice, 'tyler' : tyler }
```

and use it like that:

```
for student_name in class_list:
    student = students[student_name]
    get_average(student)
    total_class += get_average(student)
```

Note that this way, the dicts can be defined completely inside `get_class_average(class_list)`, which may be a good idea.

Comment: Is it possible to call it assigning ['lloyd', 'alice', 'tyler'] to a students_list, and then use get_class_average(stundents_list)? Actually, how can I avoid accessign wrong 'lloyd'['homework'] not specifying exact students, but using a variable containing all their names?

Comment: @user2742080 I believe I answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass students by name, first write a helper to do the mapping from names to actual student data objects; you'll need a small database like registry for that to get started:

```
STUDENTS_BY_NAME = {'alice': alice, 'lloyd': lloyd, ...}

def get_students_by_name(names):
    return [STUDENTS_BY_NAME[name] for name in names]
```

then you can do:

```
get_class_average(get_students_by_name(['alice', 'lloyd']))
```

It would be ugly to amend `get_class_average` to support passing students by name because every function should be doing exactly one thing, and only the thing that is specified by the function's name.

In the end, you might just want to declare the students in a name->data mapping format right away:

```
STUDENTS = {
    'alice': {...data here...},
    'lloyd': {...data here...},
    ...
}
```

so you wouldn't need those intermediate variables for each of the students and can just use the `STUDENTS` registry in `get_students_by_name`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same problem. I know it's not correct because I still get an error. But here's my interpretation of Elazar's answer:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

results = []

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total /= len(numbers)
    return total

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

def get_average(students):
    score = average(student["homework"] * 0.1) + average(student["quizzes"] * 0.3) +     average(student["tests"] * 0.6))

def get_class_average(classs_list):
    total = 0
    for student in class_list:
        student = student["name"]
        get_average(student)
        total_class += get_average(student)

    return average_class
```

Hope that maybe you can learn from my feeble attempt at this. I have my own question posted in this forum about this, but couldn't really tend to it due to the circumstances of my vacation. Again nevertheless, hopefully my failed attempt based on what little I could get answered might do you some good.